# A Sturm–Liouville problem on the whole space

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, sturm-liouville

Let $q \in C^\infty(\mathbb{R}) \cap L^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ be an even function, with $q(0)<0$, and assume $q$ converges exponentially fast to $\bar{q}>0$ for $x \to \pm\infty$. Let $f \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ be an odd function. Then, I am looking for a solution of
$$
-u'' + q(x)u = f(x)
$$
such that $u \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$.

The problem looks very innocent, reminiscent of a Sturm–Liouville problem (but on the whole of $\mathbb{R}$). However, the non-positivity of $q$ around $0$ jeopardizes many of my attempts to approach it. I also thought of going to the Fourier domain, but then I get stuck on an integral equation, as I am stuck on the above. Am I missing a reference where this problem is already extensively treated? Or otherwise, any suggestion on how to approach the existence of an $L^2$ solution?

Comment: Can we assume that $q_0 < q(x) < \bar{q}$ for all $x$? If not, are there any bounds placed on $q$?

Comment: The bound $q(0) \leq q(x) \leq \bar{q}$ is indeed expected, for example we can consider $q(x) = 3\tanh^2(x) - 1$.

Comment: Start by looking at the solutions of a special case, where $q=\overline{q}$ is a positive real constant function:
$$
                     -u''+\overline{q}u=0.
$$
This equation has exponential solutions, $e^{\pm \sqrt{q}x}$. Then you can form the solution of $-u''+\overline{q}u=f$. See if the solution you get meets the requirements.